# AppEngine Analytics Model with Lists of Times

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I want to log analytics data (when someone loads page X, loads a js plugin, cancels a transaction) for my AppEngine app.

I'm going to set it up as follows:
1. Event X occurs.
2. Add to taskqueue to put this event in the datastore.
3. Filter over datastore to graph and analyze usage data.

So here's the issue: I'd like create a single Analytics Model and store each event as a timestamp on a corresponding list for that action. I'm going to shard this single Model into several instances in the datastore and write to each one randomly and then combine the results for graphing.

BUT, GAE can't filter on lists, so I can't do things like filter for all events TODAY (which is what I'd really like to do).

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to shard a model. There's no limit on the number of entities you can have with a given kind name - they're all stored in the same Bigtable anyway!

It's not clear what you're trying to do that requires filtering on a list. Can you clarify? What sort of query do you want to perform?

Comment: Basically, suppose I want to log a timestamp when a page is loaded or someone logs in. Then I want to be able to run analysis on those timestamp data points - graph, etc. What's the best way to do it in GAE? I don't want to store a single Model instance for each datapoint (wasting space), but I also can't put all data into the same instance (sine DB writes are blocking).

Is this better?

Comment: @Barbara A model instance per entry would be the best way to do this. Minimize space usage by setting as many fields as possible unindexed, and use short kind names and property names (you can specify these independently of the names you use in code).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of logging this data inside your app, have you considered imbedding a proper analytics software, such as Google Analytics in your app?

Your app is not really all that different from a normal website, even if you require logins. Google Analytics will provide you a much better reporting suit than just putting data into datastore.

We did similar stuff with Omniture at my previous gig, and it worked wonderfully, for example allowing us to focus on specific browsers to support.